# Удалить строку через регулярное выражение

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста, как удалить все строки где содержится null через регулярку!
NotePad++ или EmEditor
колонки НАЙТИ и ЗАМЕНИТЬ.
Заранее благодарен!

```
INSERT INTO "MY_TABLE"("ClD", "XMLData") VALUES (25766, null);
INSERT INTO "MY_TABLE"("ClD", "XMLData") VALUES (25790, 23444);
INSERT INTO "MY_TABLE"("ClD", "XMLData") VALUES (26554, null);
```

Comment: Найти: `^.*null.*$`, Заменить на: пустая строка

Comment: https://regexr.com/61061 , но хз как с поддержкой `\b` в упомянутых редакторах...

Comment: @Akina спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Найти: ^.*null.*$, Заменить на: пустая строка

@Akina спасибо!!!